# How do I add all headers with named values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I am converting Google form submissions into pdf files and the code seems to work for the values that are questions listed in the form. however I also have multiple columns that calculate data based on answers. I'm wondering how I can add all headers to the list of constructed information.

Below is the code I'm using. However it only grabs the data from the namedValues generated from the form submission. I need to add the data from the last row of all columns into the constructed info

```
function After_Submit(e){

  const info = e.namedValues;
  const pdfFile = Create_PDF(info);  
  
  console.log(info);
  
  sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email Address to Receive file'][0],pdfFile);  
}

function sendEmail(email,pdfFile){
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Subject", "File Attached", {
    attachments: [pdfFile], 
    name: "PDF Sender"

  });
 
}
function Create_PDF(info) {
  
  const PDF_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Storage destination ID");
  const TEMP_FOLDER = DriveApp.getFolderById("Temp Folder ID");
  const PDF_Template = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID');
  
  const newTempFile = PDF_Template.makeCopy(TEMP_FOLDER);
  const  OpenDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = OpenDoc.getBody();
  
  console.log(body);
  
   body.replaceText("{{value1}}", info['value1'][0])
   body.replaceText("{{value2}}", info['value2'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{value3}}", info['value3'][0]);

  OpenDoc.saveAndClose();
  

  const BLOBPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile =  PDF_folder.createFile(BLOBPDF).setName("FLHA");
  console.log("The file has been created ");
  
  return pdfFile;

}
```

Comment: You could add those values to e.namedValues. It's just an object. It would be something like `info['property name']=[]; info['property name'].push(value);` and to remove them `info['property name'][0]; And you'd have to add your desired calculations as well which are not made very clear in your question.

Comment: This does work, the only issue I'm having is determining the last row of 'property name'. There are about 20 additional calculated properties to add and sometimes they are blank. I'll try a few things and let you know if I figure anything out

Comment: @Jml9548 - Could you share a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: Sure. The current project is a hazard assessment form. each numeric heading gets an X based on the answers provided. I used to use a document add on to generate the pdf files but the functions are limited and I'd prefer to try and script it myself.

The Template sheet is where each property gets linked. The namedValues work fine. Its the numeric headings I'm having trouble with.

Sample Sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T1DARrTn_BOU69oGig8OvPuG5g7jTl088uJnR5C64eU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **range** object from the Form Submit Event Object to get all necessary details (such as headers, newly added form data and formulated column values) and use it to create an Object that you can use to populate your PDF.

In my example below, I created a form that will populate columns **A-H** and added the formulated columns to **I-O**.

**Input:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
function After_Submit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow(); //get the row of newly added form data
  var sheet = range.getSheet(); //get the Sheet
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 15).getValues().flat(); //get the header names from A-O
  var data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, headers.length).getValues(); //get the values of newly added form data + formulated values
  var values = {}; // create an object 
  for( var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++ ){
    values[headers[i]] = data[0][i]; //add elements to values object and use headers as key
  }

  Logger.log(values);
}
```

**Note:**

- Unlike using namedValues, this method will include the column that has no data.
- If you want to adjust the number of headers to be included in your object, just change the 4th parameter of `var header`.

**Result:**

[image]

```
{4=, Location of Work=Test, 1=X, 6=, Workers Present=Test, Test2, 2=X, 5=X, 7=, Work To Be Done=Test, Timestamp=Tue Oct 12 06:06:30 GMT+08:00 2021, Environmental Hazards=Dust / Mist Fumes, Noise in area, Waste, 3=, Tasks To Be Completed=Test, Muster Point=Test, PPE Inspected=Test}
```

### References:

- [Form Submit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: This is a way better method than namedValues method. Thanks so much. Is there anyway to avoid typing the replaceText command 70 times lol?

 `body.replaceText("{{1}}", info['1'][0]);`

Comment: I am now receiving this error after updating the script. Exception: Invalid argument: replacement
    at Create_PDF(Code:37:8)
    at After_Submit(Code:11:19)

Comment: Is the header same with the text pattern in your replaceText? If yes, you can just loop through the object and use the object key as text pattern.

Comment: Please note that the content of `info` is an object. The replacement text should be `info[key]` only. And when you have key that is number, it will not work on `{{search pattern}}` pattern, I would suggest to use %search pattern% to all patterns.

Comment: I have updated all headers so that none are numbers using a letter in front of each like E1, E2, E3 ect.. I'm still receiving an error messge for replaceText. Exception: Invalid argument: replacement
    at Create_PDF(Code:37:8)
    at After_Submit(Code:13:19)