# How do you loop through an object and replace text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a script that should create a pdf file from a google form submission and grabs the data to be changed as an object. However I am using the replaceText action to make the changes to the doc and I'm getting the following error.

Exception: Invalid argument: replacement
at Create_PDF(Code:37:8)
at After_Submit(Code:13:19)

It is supposed to change the values in the generated doc file and it worked when I used the namedValues function. However now that I'm using range instead it doesn't seem to work.

```
function After_Submit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow(); //get the row of newly added form data
  var sheet = range.getSheet(); //get the Sheet
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 129).getValues().flat(); //get the header names from A-O
  var data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, headers.length).getValues(); //get the values of newly added form data + formulated values
  var values = {}; // create an object 
  for( var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++ ){
    values[headers[i]] = data[0][i]; //add elements to values object and use headers as key
  }

  Logger.log(values);
  const pdfFile = Create_PDF(values);
  sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email Address to Receive File '][0],pdfFile);
}

function sendEmail(email,pdfFile){
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Subject", "Files Attached", {
    attachments: [pdfFile], 
    name: "From Email"

  });
 
}
function Create_PDF(values) {
  const PDF_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID_1");
  const TEMP_FOLDER = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID_2");
  const PDF_Template = DriveApp.getFileById('ID_3');
  
  const newTempFile = PDF_Template.makeCopy(TEMP_FOLDER);
  const  OpenDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = OpenDoc.getBody();
  
  console.log(body);

  body.replaceText("{{Timestamp}}", values['Timestamp'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{Location}}", values['Location'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{Item1}}", values['Item1'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{Item2}}", values['Item2'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{Itme3}}", values['Item3'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e1}}", values['e1'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e2}}", values['e2'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e3}}", values['e3'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e4}}", values['e4'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e5}}", values['e5'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e6}}", values['e6'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e7}}", values['e7'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e8}}", values['e8'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e9}}", values['e9'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e10}}", values['e10'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e11}}", values['e11'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e12}}", values['e12'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e13}}", values['e13'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e14}}", values['e14'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e15}}", values['e15'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e16}}", values['e16'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e17}}", values['e17'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e18}}", values['e18'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e19}}", values['e19'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e20}}", values['e20'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e21}}", values['e21'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e22}}", values['e22'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e23}}", values['e23'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e24}}", values['e24'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e25}}", values['e25'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e26}}", values['e26'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e27}}", values['e27'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e28}}", values['e28'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e29}}", values['e29'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e30}}", values['e30'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e31}}", values['e31'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e32}}", values['e32'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e33}}", values['e33'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e34}}", values['e34'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e35}}", values['e35'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e36}}", values['e36'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e37}}", values['e37'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e38}}", values['e38'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{e39}}", values['e39'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H1}}", values['H1'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H2}}", values['H2'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H3}}", values['H3'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H4}}", values['H4'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H5}}", values['H5'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H6}}", values['H6'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H7}}", values['H7'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H8}}", values['H8'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H9}}", values['H9'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H10}}", values['H10'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H11}}", values['H11'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H12}}", values['H12'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H13}}", values['H13'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{H14}}", values['H14'][0]);


  OpenDoc.saveAndClose();
  

  const BLOBPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile =  PDF_folder.createFile(BLOBPDF).setName("FLHA");
  console.log("The file has been created ");
  
  return pdfFile;

}
```

Comment: try e.values or e.namedValues

Comment: I used nemedValues originally. However there are other cells in the spreadsheet that calculate data based on responses, and namedValues only grabs data from the submitted responses. I use range now to grab all required data, but the replaceText action no longer works to modify the doc.

Comment: Yeah I think that's a bad approach to mess with the linked sheet that way.  I prefer to leave them alone to just store responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to my answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69533174/14606052).

The error code `Exception: Invalid argument: replacement at Create_PDF(Code:37:8) at After_Submit(Code:13:19)` is caused by the null value of `values['Timestamp'][0]`. If you try to print the data type of `values['Timestamp']`, it will return a type object, since that object does not have value for index 0 to it will return a null value.

For entries that are type String, if you add `[0]` to it, it will return only the first element of the string. Example you have **"Test"** string, adding [0] to it will return **"T"**

To fix that, just remove the `[0]` in all of `body.replaceText(..., values['...'][0])` entries.

**OR**

Loop through `values` object by replacing the `body.replaceText` entries in your code with this:

```
for (const key in values) {
   body.replaceText("{{"+key+"}}", values[key]);
}
```

**Example usage:**

[image]

**Form inputs:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [JavaScript for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 2):

**Your question was how to loop through an object and replace text**

This creates an object from  Sheet0:

Sheet0:

| one | pattern |
| --- | --- |
| two | this is the pattern |
| three | pattern pattern |
| four | nothing |
| five | nothing |

Code:

```
function replacepattern() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();
  //creating object from spreadsheet
  let obj = {pA:[]};
  vs.forEach(r =>{
    obj[r[0]]=r[1];
    obj.pA.push(r[0]);
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  let oA = obj.pA.map(p => [obj[p].replace(/pattern/g,'replacement')]);//doing the replacement in an object
  sh.getRange(1,sh.getLastColumn() + 1,oA.length, oA[0].length).setValues(oA);//outputting the replaced string in the next column
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(oA));
}
```

Sheet0 after running once:

| one | pattern | replacement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| two | this is the pattern | this is the replacement |
| three | pattern pattern | replacement replacement |
| four | nothing | nothing |
| five | nothing | nothing |

Comment: This creates a ton of log files and I'm not familiar enough with the code to understand it. I already have the object created from the range . I just cant figure out quite how to update the doc with the data. replaceText keeps giving me errors

Comment: Logger.log() does not create files.

Comment: The file is created in Create_PDF(values) function.

Comment: I may have worded the question wrong. I don't want to replace the text of the object. I want to use the object to update data in a document.