# Google Sheets Apps Script: How do I loop through replaceText and pull values from one cell to replace in Google Docs template?

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I followed a few tutorials to set up a Google Docs template for a job offer letter. I made mail merge fields in the Google Doc set up as "{{FirstName}}", "{{StartDate}}", etc. I have a Google Sheet and a Google Form. I made a sheet called "Fields" where in column D, I have the "merge fields" and then in Column E, I have the values. I have been pasting lines of code to replace the merge fields with values, one-by-one. I saw a solution in another forum about how to do a loop. But after hours of practice, I couldn't get it working.

Ideally, I would like maintain the merge fields in a Google Sheet, so that I can add more. It would be lovely if I could figure out how to write an Apps Script to read any merge fields on my Google Sheet and then do the replaceText function automatically.

Right now, I have the code working one-by-one, but every time I add merge fields, I have to edit the code to find it in my Google Sheet.

I saw some code here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69545550/how-do-you-loop-through-an-object-and-replace-text#:~:text=Loop%20through%20values%20object%20by%20replacing%20the%20body.replaceText%20entries%20in%20your%20code%20with%20this%3A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69545550/how-do-you-loop-through-an-object-and-replace-text#:%7E:text=Loop%20through%20values%20object%20by%20replacing%20the%20body.replaceText%20entries%20in%20your%20code%20with%20this%3A)
that I was trying to replicate for a loop but I couldn't get it working :(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzvUt.png)

[Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mpo6.png)
[Google Docs Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkoiA.png)

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Form')
  
    //Copy template documents in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(sheet.getRange('Fields!E3').getValues()+' '+sheet.getRange('Fields!E4').getValues()+` - Offer Letter` , destinationFolder)
    
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    
    //Create constants for the Google Doc Body and Header so we can use replaceText
    const body = doc.getBody();
    const docHeader = doc.getHeader().getParent();

    //Replace text in Headers of Google Doc
    docHeader.replaceText(sheet.getRange('Fields!D3').getValues(), sheet.getRange('Fields!E3').getValues()); //First Name
    docHeader.replaceText(sheet.getRange('Fields!D4').getValues(), sheet.getRange('Fields!E4').getValues()); //Last Name

//Replace body text
    body.replaceText(sheet.getRange('Fields!D2').getValues(), sheet.getRange('Fields!E2').getValues());
    body.replaceText(sheet.getRange('Fields!D3').getValues(), sheet.getRange('Fields!E3').getValues());
    body.replaceText(sheet.getRange('Fields!D4').getValues(), sheet.getRange('Fields!E4').getValues());
    body.replaceText(sheet.getRange('Fields!D5').getValues(), sheet.getRange('Fields!E5').getValues());
    body.replaceText(sheet.getRange('Fields!D6').getValues(), sheet.getRange('Fields!E6').getValues());
    body.replaceText(sheet.getRange('Fields!D7').getValues(), sheet.getRange('Fields!E7').getValues());
    body.replaceText(sheet.getRange('Fields!D8').getValues(), sheet.getRange('Fields!E8').getValues());
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a sheet and template as shown.

[image]

[image]

Now using the following script replace all the placeholders with the text.  Notice I deliberatly leave one out.

```
function replaceText() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    values.shift(); // remove header

    let file = DriveApp.getFileById("1up..........").makeCopy(values[1][4]+" "+values[2][4]+" - Letter");
    let doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    let body = doc.getBody();

    values.forEach( row => {
        body.replaceText(row[3],row[4])
      }
    );

  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

With the following results

[image]

Reference:

- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Body.replaceText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String))